# Spark step on EMR just hangs as "Running" after done writing to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

Running PySpark 2 job on EMR 5.1.0 as a step. Even after the script is done with a `_SUCCESS` file written to S3 and Spark UI showing the job as completed, EMR still shows the step as "Running". I've waited for over an hour to see if Spark was just trying to clean itself up but the step never shows as "Completed". The last thing written in the logs is:

```
INFO MultipartUploadOutputStream: close closed:false s3://mybucket/some/path/_SUCCESS
INFO DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201611181653_0000 committed.
INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 0
```

I didn't have this problem with Spark 1.6. I've tried a bunch of different `hadoop-aws` and `aws-java-sdk` jars to no avail.

I'm using the default Spark 2.0 configurations so I don't think anything else like metadata is being written. Also the size of the data doesn't seem to have an impact on this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you aren't already, you should close your spark context.

```
sc.stop()
```

Also, if you are watching the Spark Web UI via a browser, you should close that as it sometimes keeps the spark context alive. I recall seeing this on the spark dev mailing list, but can't find the jira for it.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced this problem and resolved it by running the job in cluster deploy mode using the following spark-submit option:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster
```

It was something to do with when running in client mode the driver runs in the master instance and the spark-submit process is getting stuck despite the spark spark context closing. This was causing the instance controller to continuously polling for process as it never receives the completion signal. Running the driver on one of the instance nodes using the above option doesn't seem to have this problem. Hope this helps

Comment: In my case running with deploy-mode cluster didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with Spark on AWS EMR and I solved the issue by calling sys.exit(O) at the end of my Python script. The same worked with Scala program with System.exit(0).